# LINQ Join multiple datatables - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I have below code which I use to join multiple datatables using LINQ. The code has no errors, but it return a runtime error/InvalidOperationException saying "The source contains no DataRows."

If I comment from line where it says ***from join raw3*** to end of ***join raw4.Field("OtherString") }***, I see the data in DataTable after CopyToDataTable statement.

If I use all the datatable, I am getting InvalidOperationException "The source contains no DataRows." error. Also, I want to join all the tables with first table (firstDT).

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
datatable.Columns.Add("First_Code", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("First_Date", typeof(DateTime));
datatable.Columns.Add("OtherString", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("FirstPrice", typeof(decimal));
datatable.Columns.Add("SecondPrice", typeof(decimal));
datatable.Columns.Add("ThirdPrice", typeof(decimal));
datatable.Columns.Add("FourthPrice", typeof(decimal));

var data = from raw1 in firstDT.AsEnumerable()
            join raw2 in secondDT.AsEnumerable() on
                new { ID = raw1.Field<string>("First_Code"), Date = raw1.Field<DateTime>("First_Date"), OtherString = raw1.Field<string>("OtherString") }
                equals
                new { ID = raw2.Field<string>("Second_Code"), Date = raw2.Field<DateTime>("Second_Date"), OtherString = raw2.Field<string>("OtherString") }
            join raw3 in thirdDT.AsEnumerable() on
                new { ID = raw1.Field<string>("First_Code"), Date = raw1.Field<DateTime>("First_Date"), OtherString = raw1.Field<string>("OtherString") }
                equals
                new { ID = raw3.Field<string>("Third_Code"), Date = raw3.Field<DateTime>("Third_Date"), OtherString = raw3.Field<string>("OtherString") }
            join raw4 in fourthDT.AsEnumerable() on
                new { ID = raw1.Field<string>("First_Code"), Date = raw1.Field<DateTime>("First_Date"), OtherString = raw1.Field<string>("OtherString") }
                equals
                new { ID = raw4.Field<string>("Fourth_Code"), Date = raw4.Field<DateTime>("Fourth_Date"), OtherString = raw4.Field<string>("OtherString") }
            select datatable.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        raw1.Field<string>("First_Code"),
        raw1.Field<DateTime>("First_Date"),
        raw1.Field<string>("OtherString"),
        raw1.Field<decimal>("FirstPrice"),
        raw2.Field<decimal>("SecondPrice")
        raw3.Field<decimal>("ThirdPrice")
        raw4.Field<decimal>("FourthPrice")
    }, false);

data.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what are you asking for?

Comment: If I join firstDT and secondDT it works fine. The problem starts if I add third/extra data table to LINQ query. 
firstDT,secondDT works. firstDT,secondDT,thirdDT not working. firstDT,secondDT,thirdDT, fourthDT not working.

Comment: I want to know the reason for InvalidOpetationException/The source contains no DataRows. In other words, how do I join multiple datatables always with first datable with multiple columns.

Comment: Are you sure 3rd and 4th have at least one row? If not, getting data dynamically probably fails. If that's the case, you could check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020441/how-to-fix-the-source-contains-no-datarows)